# Dummit and Foote 7.4 ex 34

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mathcal{R}=\mathcal{C}[\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}], M_c=\{f \in \mathcal{R}: f(c)=0\}, I=\{f \in \mathcal{R},f$ has compact support$\}$.  Show a) $I$ is not a prime ideal b) If $I \subset M$ and $M$ is a maximal ideal then $M$ is not $M_c$ for any $c$

My attemept;

a) Take $f(x)=max\{sin(x),0\}$, $g(x)=max\{sin(x-\pi),0\}$ Then $(fg)(x)=0$ and clearly $0 \in I$ but neither $g,f$ are in $I$

b) Given $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $2c|1-\frac{x}{2c}|\chi[|x|\leq 2c]$ is in $I$ and so in $M$ but not in $M_c$

a) feels good but b) feels sketchy. I never use that $M$ is maximal or even any properties of the ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b) It is indeed enough to show that $I\not\subseteq M_c$ for every $c$. Pick real $c$. Consider any piecewise linear continuous function $f(x)$ which is equal to $c+1$ on the interval $[c-1,c+1]$ and zero on the intervals $(-\infty, c-2]$ and $[c+2,\infty)$. Then $f$ is in $I$ but not in $M_c$.

Comment: I don't understand how do you define $f$ on $(c+1,c+2)$ and $(c-2,c-1)$ such that $f$ become continuous on whole $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You can draw a graph of $f$. The graph is $0$ outside $[c-2,c+2]$, a constant $c+1$ on $[c-1,c+1]$, a line interval (segment) on $[c-2,c-1]$ and a line interval on $[c+1,c+2]$. These line intervals make the function continuous.

Comment: Hmm, yes. But here I have one question, we know a maximal ideal $\iff$ prime ideal in this PID . So how this  assume $I\subset M $ , where $M$ is maximal , is correct, as we know $I$ is not a prime ideal.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What does PID have to do with the OP or my answer?

Comment: I am saying about this **If $I \subset M$ and $M$ is a maximal ideal**,. How is it possible,as $I$ is not prime ideal.

Comment: How do $M$ look like , if there some?

Comment: If $I$ is not inside $M_c$ then any maximal ideal containing $I$ is not inside $M_c$ either. Just draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: You do not need to know how $M$ looks like, You only need to know that $M$ exists. In a unital ring every ideal is inside a maximal ideal (it follows from Zorn lemma).

Comment: Thanks, for the reply!!